# How to query Sensu API with curl and auth credentials?

Tags: authentication, curl, basic-authentication, sensu

I'm trying to query Sensu API (any endpoint) using API credentials and curl, like the following:

$ curl -a user:password http://sensu_api:url:4567/clients

I'ts giving a:  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

These credentials are the ones configured in my api settings within /etc/sensu/config.json and uchiwa is using them to connect without any issues. Maybe I'm missusing curl to query it. Don't know why.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your the API port is reachable from the outside? Try to run the command on your sensu server using: 
`curl -u user:password http://127.0.0.1:4567/clients`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using -u instead of -a

-u, --user

Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication. Overrides -n, --netrc and --netrc-optional.

If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password.

The user name and passwords are split up on the first colon, which makes it impossible to use a colon in the user name with this option. The password can, still.

When using Kerberos V5 with a Windows based server you should include the Windows domain name in the user name, in order for the server to successfully obtain a Kerberos Ticket. If you don't then the initial authentication handshake may fail.

When using NTLM, the user name can be specified simply as the user name, without the domain, if there is a single domain and forest in your setup for example.

To specify the domain name use either Down-Level Logon Name or UPN (User Principal Name) formats. For example, EXAMPLE\user and user@example.com respectively.

If you use a Windows SSPI-enabled curl binary and perform Kerberos V5, Negotiate, NTLM or Digest authentication then you can tell curl to select the user name and password from your environment by specifying a single colon with this option: "-u :".

If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.